# I tried to install google-chrome on ubuntu 22.10 using the terminal but this following errors

Tags: networking, google-chrome

By running this command `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.db`

and I got this error

````
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2023-06-18 17:58:59 ERROR 404: Not Found.```
````

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled the DEB package extension which is a part of the URL and it should be `..._amd64.deb` and not `..._amd64.db` which had rendered the URL incorrect and pointing to a non-existence URI and hence the error:

```
ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

So, download it with:

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Then, install it with:

```
sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```